# How is the period variable calculated for yahoo finance historicals?

Tags: yahoo-finance

When you set the date range for historical prices the js redirects with url variables period1 and period2. For example for `Time Period: Jul 30, 2015 - Aug 30, 2015` the resulting url is as follows. `period1=1438228800&period2=1440907200`

https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?period1=1438228800&period2=1440907200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

Anyone know how period1 and period2 were calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unix timestamp (seconds since January 1, 1970)](https://www.epochconverter.com)